# Network-related error for sql connection

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am trying to create a simple database using entity framework code first but when I run my project I get exception on line where i am retrieving list from database:

**Exception:**

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

**Code:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{    
    using(var db=new OdeToFooddb())
    {
        var model = (from r in db.Restaurants select r).ToList();
        return View(model);
     }
 }
```

**Model:**

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Check your connection string.

Comment: What should I check in it @SirwanAfifi ?

Comment: use SQL Server Management Studio and attempt connecting to your server;

Comment: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/15/a-troubleshooting-guide-for-entity-framework-connections-amp-migrations.aspx

Comment: this is due to connection between the framework and sql server. Test the sql connection

Comment: Still not working I have tried making a constructor and coping connection string from there. @anand

Comment: first your framework is reciving any data from server. there is nothing to do with the controller code. you have check the connection

Comment: what to check in it ? @anand

Comment: first check your sql connection test